# In WSO2 ESB, why SOAPAction was lost if request initiated within scheduler task?

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

The requirement for the project is to make a web service call and save its response daily. The web service expects a fix value and a date value in YYYYMMDD format. To accomplish that, I create a SEQUENCE does the following:

1. Create a payload with the required parameters for the web service
2. Call the web service endpoint with the payload
3. save the response

I then create a proxy service that use the SEQUENCE. When I run the proxy using SoapUI, everything works as expected. Then I create a schedule task to call the sequence. When the scheduler task runs, the sequence fails to make a successful web service call. When I examine the log entries, I observe that the values for both SOAPAction and WSA-Action (from the defined endpoint) are null in the case of scheduler task; while they have the proper values (https://hostname/Get_Daily_Usage) in the case of proxy service. I am suspending whether this is the root cause of the issue. If it is the root cause, how can I fix it? Please help shed some lights if you have insights of how this works. Below are the log entries from each case. Thank you in advance.

Log entries resulted from the execution of schedule task

```
TID: [-1] [] [2016-11-15 11:34:00,038] DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.mediators.builtin.CallMediator} -  Start : Call mediator - Non Blocking Call {org.apache.synapse.mediators.builtin.CallMediator}
TID: [-1] [] [2016-11-15 11:34:00,039] DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.endpoints.IndirectEndpoint} -  Loading real endpoint with key : MyWSEndpoint {org.apache.synapse.endpoints.IndirectEndpoint}
TID: [-1] [] [2016-11-15 11:34:00,039] DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.endpoints.EndpointContext} -  Checking if endpoint : MyWSEndpoint currently at state ACTIVE can be used now? {org.apache.synapse.endpoints.EndpointContext}
TID: [-1] [] [2016-11-15 11:34:00,039] DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.endpoints.AddressEndpoint} -  Sending message through endpoint : MyWSEndpoint resolving to address = https://hostname/WebService_V3/WebService_S.asmx {org.apache.synapse.endpoints.AddressEndpoint}
TID: [-1] [] [2016-11-15 11:34:00,039] DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.endpoints.AddressEndpoint} -  SOAPAction: null {org.apache.synapse.endpoints.AddressEndpoint}
TID: [-1] [] [2016-11-15 11:34:00,039] DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.endpoints.AddressEndpoint} -  WSA-Action: null {org.apache.synapse.endpoints.AddressEndpoint}
TID: [-1] [] [2016-11-15 11:34:00,039] DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2FlexibleMEPClient} -  Sending [add = false] [sec = false] [mtom = false] [swa = false] [format = null] [force soap11=false] [force soap12=false] [pox=false] [get=false] [encoding=null] [to=https://hostname/WebService_V3/WebService_S.asmx] {org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2FlexibleMEPClient}
TID: [-1] [] [2016-11-15 11:34:00,039] DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2FlexibleMEPClient} -  Message [Original Request Message ID : urn:uuid:28b97f1e-ea82-4786-8921-cba8e2786b8d] [New Cloned Request Message ID : urn:uuid:a6439020-a89b-4683-8326-6b5846a63a86] {org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2FlexibleMEPClient}
TID: [-1] [] [2016-11-15 11:34:00,039] DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.SynapseCallbackReceiver} -  Callback added. Total callbacks waiting for : 1 {org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.SynapseCallbackReceiver}
TID: [-1] [] [2016-11-15 11:34:00,103] DEBUG {org.apache.axis2.transport.http.ApplicationXMLFormatter} -  contentType set from messageContext =application/xml {org.apache.axis2.transport.http.ApplicationXMLFormatter}
TID: [-1] [] [2016-11-15 11:34:00,104] DEBUG {org.apache.axis2.transport.http.ApplicationXMLFormatter} -  (NOTE) contentType from format is=application/soap+xml {org.apache.axis2.transport.http.ApplicationXMLFormatter}
TID: [-1] [] [2016-11-15 11:34:00,104] DEBUG {org.apache.axis2.transport.http.ApplicationXMLFormatter} -  contentType returned =application/xml; charset=UTF-8 {org.apache.axis2.transport.http.ApplicationXMLFormatter}
TID: [-1] [] [2016-11-15 11:34:00,104] DEBUG {org.apache.axis2.transport.http.ApplicationXMLFormatter} -  start writeTo() {org.apache.axis2.transport.http.ApplicationXMLFormatter}
TID: [-1] [] [2016-11-15 11:34:00,104] DEBUG {org.apache.axis2.transport.http.ApplicationXMLFormatter} -  end writeTo() {org.apache.axis2.transport.http.ApplicationXMLFormatter}
TID: [-1] [] [2016-11-15 11:34:00,105] DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.mediators.builtin.CallMediator} -  End : Call mediator - Non Blocking Call {org.apache.synapse.mediators.builtin.CallMediator}
TID: [-1] [] [2016-11-15 11:34:00,105] DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.mediators.filters.FilterMediator} -  End : Filter mediator  {org.apache.synapse.mediators.filters.FilterMediator}
TID: [-1] [] [2016-11-15 11:34:00,105] DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.mediators.base.SequenceMediator} -  End : Sequence <MyWSCallSeq> {org.apache.synapse.mediators.base.SequenceMediator}
TID: [-1] [] [2016-11-15 11:34:00,200] DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.SynapseCallbackReceiver} -  Callback removed for request message id : urn:uuid:a6439020-a89b-4683-8326-6b5846a63a86. Pending callbacks count : 0 {org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.SynapseCallbackReceiver}
TID: [-1234] [] [2016-11-15 11:34:00,201] DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.SynapseCallbackReceiver} -  Synapse received an asynchronous response message {org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.SynapseCallbackReceiver}
TID: [-1234] [] [2016-11-15 11:34:00,201] DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.SynapseCallbackReceiver} -  Received To: null {org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.SynapseCallbackReceiver}
TID: [-1234] [] [2016-11-15 11:34:00,201] DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.SynapseCallbackReceiver} -  SOAPAction:  {org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.SynapseCallbackReceiver}
TID: [-1234] [] [2016-11-15 11:34:00,201] DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.SynapseCallbackReceiver} -  WSA-Action:  {org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.SynapseCallbackReceiver}
TID: [-1234] [] [2016-11-15 11:34:00,201] DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.SynapseCallbackReceiver} -  Body : 
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?><soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><soapenv:Body/></soapenv:Envelope> {org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.SynapseCallbackReceiver}
TID: [-1234] [] [2016-11-15 11:34:00,201] DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.SOAPUtils} -  convert SOAP11 to SOAP12 {org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.SOAPUtils}
TID: [-1234] [] [2016-11-15 11:34:00,202] DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2SynapseEnvironment} -  Injecting MessageContext {org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2SynapseEnvironment}
TID: [-1234] [] [2016-11-15 11:34:00,202] DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2SynapseEnvironment} -  Response received for the Continuation Call service invocation {org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2SynapseEnvironment}
TID: [-1234] [] [2016-11-15 11:34:00,202] DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2SynapseEnvironment} -  Mediating response using the ContinuationStateStack {org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2SynapseEnvironment}
TID: [-1234] [] [2016-11-15 11:34:00,203] DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.mediators.base.SequenceMediator} -  Mediating using the SeqContinuationState type : NAMED name : MyWSCallSeq {org.apache.synapse.mediators.base.SequenceMediator}
TID: [-1234] [] [2016-11-15 11:34:00,203] DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.mediators.base.SequenceMediator} -  Setting the onError handler : UsageDownloadFailSeq for the sequence : MyWSCallSeq {org.apache.synapse.mediators.base.SequenceMediator}
TID: [-1234] [] [2016-11-15 11:34:00,203] DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.mediators.filters.FilterMediator} -  Filter mediator : Mediating from ContinuationState {org.apache.synapse.mediators.filters.FilterMediator}
TID: [-1234] [] [2016-11-15 11:34:00,204] DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.mediators.filters.FilterMediator} -  Sequence <FilterMediator> :: mediate() {org.apache.synapse.mediators.filters.FilterMediator}
TID: [-1234] [] [2016-11-15 11:34:00,204] DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.mediators.filters.FilterMediator} -  Mediation started from mediator position : 2 {org.apache.synapse.mediators.filters.FilterMediator}
```

Log entries resulted from the execution of proxy service call.

```
TID: [-1234] [] [2016-11-15 10:57:54,993] DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.mediators.builtin.CallMediator} -  Start : Call mediator - Non Blocking Call {org.apache.synapse.mediators.builtin.CallMediator}
TID: [-1234] [] [2016-11-15 10:57:54,994] DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.config.SynapseConfiguration} -  There is no local registry entry for key : MyWSEndpoint {org.apache.synapse.config.SynapseConfiguration}
TID: [-1234] [] [2016-11-15 10:57:54,994] DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.endpoints.IndirectEndpoint} -  Loading real endpoint with key : MyWSEndpoint {org.apache.synapse.endpoints.IndirectEndpoint}
TID: [-1234] [] [2016-11-15 10:57:54,994] DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.endpoints.EndpointContext} -  Checking if endpoint : MyWSEndpoint currently at state ACTIVE can be used now? {org.apache.synapse.endpoints.EndpointContext}
TID: [-1234] [] [2016-11-15 10:57:54,994] DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.endpoints.AddressEndpoint} -  Sending message through endpoint : MyWSEndpoint resolving to address = https://hostname/WebService_V3/WebService_S.asmx {org.apache.synapse.endpoints.AddressEndpoint}
TID: [-1234] [] [2016-11-15 10:57:54,994] DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.endpoints.AddressEndpoint} -  SOAPAction: https://hostname/Get_Daily_Usage {org.apache.synapse.endpoints.AddressEndpoint}
TID: [-1234] [] [2016-11-15 10:57:54,994] DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.endpoints.AddressEndpoint} -  WSA-Action: https://hostname/Get_Daily_Usage {org.apache.synapse.endpoints.AddressEndpoint}
TID: [-1234] [] [2016-11-15 10:57:54,994] DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2FlexibleMEPClient} -  Sending [add = false] [sec = false] [mtom = false] [swa = false] [format = null] [force soap11=false] [force soap12=false] [pox=false] [get=false] [encoding=null] [to=https://hostname/WebService_V3/WebService_S.asmx] {org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2FlexibleMEPClient}
TID: [-1234] [] [2016-11-15 10:57:54,994] DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2FlexibleMEPClient} -  Message [Original Request Message ID : urn:uuid:e5056045-596c-48ce-bf1f-0183562db4de] [New Cloned Request Message ID : urn:uuid:cb5852f6-994f-4da0-acbd-1ff064449253] {org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2FlexibleMEPClient}
TID: [-1234] [] [2016-11-15 10:57:54,994] DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.SynapseCallbackReceiver} -  Callback added. Total callbacks waiting for : 1 {org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.SynapseCallbackReceiver}
TID: [-1] [] [2016-11-15 10:57:55,055] DEBUG {org.apache.axis2.transport.http.SOAPMessageFormatter} -  contentType from the OMOutputFormat =application/soap+xml {org.apache.axis2.transport.http.SOAPMessageFormatter}
TID: [-1] [] [2016-11-15 10:57:55,056] DEBUG {org.apache.axis2.transport.http.SOAPMessageFormatter} -  contentType returned =application/soap+xml; charset=UTF-8; action="https://hostname/Get_Daily_Usage" {org.apache.axis2.transport.http.SOAPMessageFormatter}
TID: [-1234] [] [2016-11-15 10:57:55,058] DEBUG {org.apache.axis2.transport.http.SOAPMessageFormatter} -  start writeTo() {org.apache.axis2.transport.http.SOAPMessageFormatter}
TID: [-1234] [] [2016-11-15 10:57:55,058] DEBUG {org.apache.axis2.transport.http.SOAPMessageFormatter} -    preserve=false {org.apache.axis2.transport.http.SOAPMessageFormatter}
TID: [-1234] [] [2016-11-15 10:57:55,058] DEBUG {org.apache.axis2.transport.http.SOAPMessageFormatter} -    isOptimized=false {org.apache.axis2.transport.http.SOAPMessageFormatter}
TID: [-1234] [] [2016-11-15 10:57:55,058] DEBUG {org.apache.axis2.transport.http.SOAPMessageFormatter} -    isDoingSWA=false {org.apache.axis2.transport.http.SOAPMessageFormatter}
TID: [-1234] [] [2016-11-15 10:57:55,059] DEBUG {org.apache.axis2.transport.http.SOAPMessageFormatter} -  end writeTo() {org.apache.axis2.transport.http.SOAPMessageFormatter}
TID: [-1234] [] [2016-11-15 10:57:55,060] DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.mediators.builtin.CallMediator} -  End : Call mediator - Non Blocking Call {org.apache.synapse.mediators.builtin.CallMediator}
TID: [-1234] [] [2016-11-15 10:57:55,060] DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.mediators.filters.FilterMediator} -  End : Filter mediator  {org.apache.synapse.mediators.filters.FilterMediator}
TID: [-1234] [] [2016-11-15 10:57:55,060] DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.mediators.base.SequenceMediator} -  End : Sequence <MyWSCallSeq> {org.apache.synapse.mediators.base.SequenceMediator}
TID: [-1234] [] [2016-11-15 10:57:55,060] DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.mediators.base.SequenceMediator} -  End : Sequence key=<Value {name ='null', keyValue ='MyWSCallSeq'}> {org.apache.synapse.mediators.base.SequenceMediator}
TID: [-1234] [] [2016-11-15 10:57:55,060] DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.mediators.base.SequenceMediator} -  End : Sequence <anonymous> {org.apache.synapse.mediators.base.SequenceMediator}
TID: [-1] [] [2016-11-15 10:57:55,397] DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.SynapseCallbackReceiver} -  Callback removed for request message id : urn:uuid:cb5852f6-994f-4da0-acbd-1ff064449253. Pending callbacks count : 0 {org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.SynapseCallbackReceiver}
TID: [-1234] [] [2016-11-15 10:57:55,399] DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.SynapseCallbackReceiver} -  Synapse received an asynchronous response message {org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.SynapseCallbackReceiver}
TID: [-1234] [] [2016-11-15 10:57:55,400] DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.SynapseCallbackReceiver} -  Received To: null {org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.SynapseCallbackReceiver}
TID: [-1234] [] [2016-11-15 10:57:55,400] DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.SynapseCallbackReceiver} -  SOAPAction:  {org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.SynapseCallbackReceiver}
TID: [-1234] [] [2016-11-15 10:57:55,400] DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.SynapseCallbackReceiver} -  WSA-Action:  {org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.SynapseCallbackReceiver}
TID: [-1234] [] [2016-11-15 10:57:55,400] DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.SynapseCallbackReceiver} -  Body : 
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?><soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><soapenv:Body/></soapenv:Envelope> {org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.SynapseCallbackReceiver}
TID: [-1234] [] [2016-11-15 10:57:55,400] DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.SOAPUtils} -  convert SOAP11 to SOAP12 {org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.SOAPUtils}
TID: [-1234] [] [2016-11-15 10:57:55,400] DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2SynapseEnvironment} -  Injecting MessageContext {org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2SynapseEnvironment}
TID: [-1234] [] [2016-11-15 10:57:55,400] DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2SynapseEnvironment} -  Response received for the Continuation Call service invocation {org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2SynapseEnvironment}
TID: [-1234] [] [2016-11-15 10:57:55,400] DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2SynapseEnvironment} -  Mediating response using the ContinuationStateStack {org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2SynapseEnvironment}
TID: [-1234] [] [2016-11-15 10:57:55,401] DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.ProxyService} -  Setting specified anonymous fault-sequence for proxy {org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.ProxyService}
TID: [-1234] [] [2016-11-15 10:57:55,401] DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.mediators.base.SequenceMediator} -  Mediating using the SeqContinuationState type : NAMED name : MyWSCallSeq {org.apache.synapse.mediators.base.SequenceMediator}
TID: [-1234] [] [2016-11-15 10:57:55,401] DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.mediators.base.SequenceMediator} -  Setting the onError handler : UsageDownloadFailSeq for the sequence : MyWSCallSeq {org.apache.synapse.mediators.base.SequenceMediator}
TID: [-1234] [] [2016-11-15 10:57:55,401] DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.mediators.filters.FilterMediator} -  Filter mediator : Mediating from ContinuationState {org.apache.synapse.mediators.filters.FilterMediator}
TID: [-1234] [] [2016-11-15 10:57:55,401] DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.mediators.filters.FilterMediator} -  Sequence <FilterMediator> :: mediate() {org.apache.synapse.mediators.filters.FilterMediator}
TID: [-1234] [] [2016-11-15 10:57:55,401] DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.mediators.filters.FilterMediator} -  Mediation started from mediator position : 2 {org.apache.synapse.mediators.filters.FilterMediator}
```

Answer (score 4):

Well, it's a good question. But when you send a request to your proxy service you are sending all the necessary headers such as SOAPAction etc. But task is some thing self triggered and executed and uses Quartz scheduling behind the covers. Therefore you need to set all the necessary Headers in your synapse configuration when it comes to a Task. To do so please add the following property into your task's synapse configuration before calling the endpoint using either send or call mediator.

```
<property name="SOAPAction" scope="transport" value="urn:getQuote"/>
```

Hope this helps. Happy coding !

Comment: I did that but SOAPAction was still not set.  Maybe I didn't do it correctly, let me try again.

Comment: Sure, go ahead and let me know. You may enable wirelogs to see HTTP headers if you need.

Answer (score 0):

I'd tried the suggested solution, but somehow I have trouble getting task working with my Proxy. So I simply use curl to involve my proxy instead. That works perfectly. Thank for your help.